# Can I change values of private fields during debug?

Tags: java, debugging, private, field

For the debugging purposes I need to change the value of the private field.
I use Eclipse for debugging, and I am able to change variables during debug process, but I have no access to the private variables. I tried to use a reflection in a change value view to set the field as "accessible" manually, but it looks like it doesn`t work.
Do you know any IDE/framework/plugin or something that could allow it?

Comment: in my experience, I managed to change the values of any members, as long as the debugger was in the right stack-frame. can you provide more details regarding how you debug?

Comment: Well, maybe my description of the problem was incomplete.
For example, I have an object "data "of class "Data" with the private field named "mappy". "mappy" contains a map of objects. For example, I need to insert an additional value into it.
In the "Change value" window, I can create new map in code, fill it with new values, but I can`t get existing map or run any it`s methods (put or something). 
I can`t find a way of getting "data.mappy" object, though I can get fields with "public" modifier.

Comment: i don't understand your expectation to "run" some object's method while the program is halted on a breakpoint. who do you think will execute the put() call? the best you can do is MAYBE backtrack a little and if the IDE lets you, rerun some of the code.

Comment: Why is it impossible to add extra some kind of NOP instructions in the running code, so the program could stand on a breakpoint and JVM could execute my put() or something else at the same time?
I can`t find any technical problems here.

Comment: it's not only some memory space left there as spare for you to add/inject some more code (there are situations in which this is done, e.g. instrumentation for profiling). you also want to call functions; this implies messing with the stack, so a few extra bytes of NOOPs will not help you. I recommend stepping back so you can find what really is the problem with your code. maybe then open a new question so we can help?

Comment: @Dan Arbitrary code *can* be executed/evalutated in the context of the current stack frame (while the thread is halted at a breakpoint) using the 'Display' view. I'm not sure how it's implemented, but it's certainly possible.

Answer (score 3):

In Eclipse you can go to **variable view** which lists all your variables.

Here you can right click on the member variable which you want to change and select **change value** option, which pops up a separate window to change the value. which will take into effect from then onwards.

Comment: For primitives, there's no need to even use 'Change Value' from the context menu. Just click the value (to select it), change it, and press enter.

Answer (score 1):

Yuo can use reflection to set field value (Spring provides convenient [`ReflectionTestUtil`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html)):

```
  Class<?> c = foo.getClass();
  Field field = c.getDeclaredField("valid");
  field.setAccessible(true);
  field.set(valid, Boolean.FALSE);
```

Also you shouldn't have any problems with setting private field's value in the debugger, it doesn't actually matter if it is private or not.

Answer (score 1):

Just tested with eclipse - no problem. The test application was like this:

```
 public class DebugTest {
   private static int i = 5;
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println(args.length);  // dummy line to set a breakpoint
     System.out.println(i);
   }
 }
```

I set a BP on that dummy line, started the debugger, then I changed the value for `i` in the Variables view from five to six, continued and the output was 6.

There's just one thing: maybe, you can't *see* the private variables in your Variables view. Open the views menu (the button with the triangle), select *Java* and switch on the missing items. Static constants was disabled by default - maybe that's your problem.

Comment: Well, maybe my description of the problem was incomplete. For example, I have an object "data "of class "Data" with the private field named "mappy". "mappy" contains a map of objects. For example, I need to insert an additional value into it. In the "Change value" window, I can create new map in code, fill it with new values, but I can`t get existing map or run any it`s methods (put or something). I can`t find a way of getting "data.mappy" object, though I can get fields with "public" modifier.

Answer (score -2):

As your are delcaring varible as private and you want to modifiy the value at debug level, this will not happen with any of the IDE/plugins. Every IDE will follow the basic principals.

Comment: private access relates to how other objects relate to this object. the debugger is not an object in the system.